# Should a table's primary key be a column in another index for that table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, ddl

Let's say I have a table like this. The Id is the primary key, so I know I get an index on that.

```
CREATE TABLE Employer
(
    Id VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    EntityId VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    Address1 VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    Address2 VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    City VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    JobTitle VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    StateCode VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    ZipCode VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Employer_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC)
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

Let's say I add another index to help with some special searching (though the reason why isn't really relevant). Is there a reason to include Id (the primary key) as one of the columns in the index? I've had SQL Experts tell me this is a waste of space since the index will already include the primary key in some manner.

```
CREATE INDEX [idxEmployerByNameAddress1City] on [Employer] ([EntityId], [Id], [Name], [Address1], [City])
```

Comment: **PLEASE** - don't make a `VARCHAR(64)` your clustered index! This is really horribly bad for performance.... the clustered index on a SQL Server table should be small (4-8 bytes) and fixed-width (not variable-width, like `VARCHAR(64)`) - an `INT IDENTITY` is nearly perfect. Read [Kimberly Tripp's Ever-increasing clustering key – the Clustered Index Debate……….again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/) blog post and anything she posts on clustered indexes - she's the *Queen of SQL Server indexing* - follow her advice!

Comment: And your clustering key (which by default the primary key is) will automatically be part of every single non-clustered index - yet another reason why the clustering key should be small and perform well! But adding the `ID` separately is not a waste of space - it's included in that index anyway, and if you explicitly specify it, SQL Serve will not duplicate it -> no space is being wasted.

Comment: I agree about the VARCHAR(64) thing. It's a legacy thing at this point for our app and there is actually a semi-good reason for it. So it's hard to change right now. But in our next version of the app we are planning to switch to big ints or guids.

Comment: If you're switching - ***please*** don't switch to GUID's ! Again: [Kimberly Tripp: GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/) - GUIDs are **horribly bad** for a clustering key. Avoid them. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

If your secondary index does not start with the primary key column(s) then the primary key is irrelevant for the secondary index.

On the other hand, if your index is unique based on the first two columns, as it looks like might be the case here, then there is no point in having further columns in the key - that just wastes space in the index.

Comment: Good point on the space waste. Would it make sense to move those to the INCLUDE clause? Those columns are part of the SELECT list of the query that this index is designed for I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are used for a variety of purposes.  One of them is to satisfy queries which only use columns in the index.  So, if you have a query like:

```
select col, max(pk)
from t
group by col
```

And you have an index on `t(col)`, then the query has to fetch values of `pk` from the data pages.  If the primary key is in the index, then the original data pages are not necessary.

So, there are circumstances where including the primary key in the index is a good idea.

By the way, I totally agree with the comment that the primary key should not be a varchar(64).  I would encourage you to use an integer primary key, using `identity()`.  And, for some reason, I think it is a bad idea to have primary keys of variable length -- probably because of the confusion between, say, `'A'` and `'  A'` -- which are different, but might not look different when printed out.

I would further make that point that if the primary key is stored in other tables, then the issue of wasted space in the index is moot.  You are wasting so much space storing such large primary keys that wasting a bit more in an index is not a major problem.